# Use Visual Studio Code with old vc library

Tags: c++

I wanna compile my cmake project with visual studio code. But the project using old c++ vs 2005 compiler with vc80 library. Currently i using clion, its supporting all after little configures. Can posible use the vs.code with vc80 library and compiler?

Comment: Depends on the library and type of library. Is it a statistically linked or dynamically linked library? Are the parameters being passed around [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType)?

Comment: Trivial is c++ 11. But like i asking in the topic, it is a old compiler. From the Microsoft Visual C++ 8.0 (Microsoft Visual Studio 2005).  _MSC_VER is 1500.

Comment: Trivial was defined formally recently. In the old days we called it POD-Plain Old Data. You can expect a great deal of portability when you have an interface that passes strings as null-terminated character arrays. You can't expect the same passing `std::string` because the implementation details are non-trivial (using trivial in the English language context here) and not fixed.